# create RDD using pyspark where key is the first field of the record and the value is the entire record

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How can we create a RDD using pyspark where key is the first field of the record and the value is the entire record?

```
(u'Joe', u'44', 21, u'41', u'1‘, u’1’),
(u‘Mel', u'13', 3, u'30', u'50‘, u’6’)
...
```

to

```
(u’Joe’, (u'Joe', u'44', 21, u'41', u'1‘, u’1’)),
(u’Mel’, (u‘Mel', u'13', 3, u'30', u'50‘, u’6’))
...
```

Comment: Show something you have tried...

Comment: I am new to spark, but these are following commands i attempted.
rdd2 = rdd1.groupByKey()

Comment: rdd2 = rdd1.reduceByKey(lambda (x,y): [x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5]])

Comment: What is your end goal? Why do you need the key-value pairs like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pyspark.rdd.keyBy()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.keyBy):

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([('Joe', '44', 21,'41','1','1'),('Mel', '13', 3, '30', '50', '6')])

>>> rdd.keyBy(lambda r: r[0]).collect()
[('Joe', ('Joe', '44', 21, '41', '1', '1')), ('Mel', ('Mel', '13', 3, '30', '50', '6'))]
```

Comment: I have a text file with 1000's of records. as Joe,44,21,41,1,1 and so on.
I used rdd0 = sc.textFile("somefile.txt") then
used rdd1 = rdd0.map(lambda line:line.split(",")) and now I want to create key-pair.
Hope you understand this, the above solution does not worked for me.

Comment: Have you tried `rdd1 = rdd0.map(lambda line:line.split(",")).keyBy(lambda r: r[0])`?

Comment: As far as I have studied, transformations include reduceByKey or groupByKey etc. . Is there any documentation for keyBy transformation?

Comment: @yatinsingla, I edited Bala's answer to include a link to the docs. Please consider deleting the answer you posted as its the same as this one. If you want to, add it as a comment.

Comment: sure and thanks for the making me aware of that. first time i am posting a question, did not know how to reply

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `map` function as below

```
rdd.map(lambda row: (row[0], row))
```